# Unable to reset mysql root password for windows 10

Tags: mysql, installation

I had installed mysql 5.7 and later *uninstalled* it. I had set a **password** which I have **forgotten** . Now, when I try to install mysql 5.7 again using mysql installer,**it asks for password before installing**.
I tried to reset the password using the procedure shown in dev.mysql page,youtube but **all in vain**.**I am unable to reset the password**.
 Methods I tried are:
1)setting the mysql-init.txt in C:\ as `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';` 
2)setting the mysql-init.txt in C:\ as `UPDATE mysql.user
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

1)running the command prompt in admin mode and running `C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
C:\> mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt`

Nothing actually seems to work. I get the *wrong password error* again when I try to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passwords of MySQL are stored inside the MySQL database.

Delete the database data files. And see what the installer says then....

You can find your database data files location in the `my.ini`

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to specify the correct data directory via `--datadir`:

```
mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt --datadir="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data" --console
```

It was by default trying to use: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data

*As mentioned by @sliver, you can find the data location in the my.ini file.*

Answer (score 0):

Add below queries to `mysql-init.txt`

```
ALTER USER `"root"`@`"localhost"` IDENTIFIED BY `"root@123"`;
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD(`"root@123"`)
WHERE User = `"root"` AND Host = `"localhost"`;
```

and run

```
mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

place the file `reset.txt`

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
```

execute the below command

```
mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt --datadir="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data"
```

Comment: mine's will say defaults-file is a unknown variable.